# Import DBF file into SQL Server : error "The search key was not found in any record"

Tags: sql-server, dbf

I'm trying to import an external vendor's `,dbf` file into our SQL Server 2016 database for reporting. I've created a linked server and can import from most of the tables except for some which provide the error

> The Search key was not found in any record

I'm doing a simple select to test the connection

```
SELECT * FROM [LINKED_SERVER]...[packet]
```

If I copy the `.DBF` file to my computer and use "DBF Viewer 2000" to remove empty records, the select query works fine, so suspect it's something in the file that is corrupted.

I copy the `.DBF` file to my DB server before I import it. The vendor insists the `.DBF` file isn't corrupt, so I need to handle this on my side. Is there a way to handle this in SQL? Alternatively, does anyone know of a free command line application that I can use to run a repair and remove empty records?

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause of this error is **space** in **column names**. Carefully check leading space, trailing space and also space inside of the column name.

Comment: Thanks. If i select top 100 it works fine, also check and can't see any spaces in the columne names.

Comment: You mentioned that you can successfully process file locally. Just upload the fixed file back to the server.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am not able to write the db file back to the vendors system. I need to try automate the process of importing.